# Is there any way to Read BeautifulSoup output with pandas to read Tables?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have tried this Way

````
data = web_soup.findAll("table", {"id": "product-review-table"})```
print(pd.read_html(data))
````

Error Returned:
TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'ResultSet

data contain a complete table. I want to read only specific table from Url, By passing url to pd.read_html() it will get all tables but to save execution time i just want to read a specific table. How may i do it ?

Comment: i already got the answer, the above provided information is enough to understand by any professional.
See the accepted answer,  have he faced any issue by description of my problem ?

Comment: _i already got the answer_ So what? _the above provided information is enough to understand by any professional_ When did that standard replace those defined in the help center and on meta? The only saving grace is that this question is trivial, and practically identical issues have been previously discussed many times on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**:

```
pd.read_html(str(data))
```

**Longer answer**:

The input to [*`read_html()`*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) can be a string.

From the docs:

```
pandas.read_html(io, ..):
... 
io : str or file-like
    A URL, a file-like object, or a raw string containing HTML...

...
```

The output of `findAll` (or `find_all`) is a `ResultSet` object.

The string representation of the `ResultSet` object can be obtained using `str(ResultSetObject)`.

```
data = web_soup.findAll("table", {"id": "product-review-table"})
print(pd.read_html(str(data)))
```